# не устанавливается приложение на эмулятор

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator

приложение было удален в процессе попытки решиния проблемы но до этого не запускалось
ошибка такая(logcat):

```
Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1:/data/app/~~rOJavvepXulcmXHF12NUgw==/com.example.notes-IRjFe-XtfnNNbGduYMXN-g==/base.apk
Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~rOJavvepXulcmXHF12NUgw==/com.example.notes-IRjFe-XtfnNNbGduYMXN-g==/base.apk
Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.notes/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.notes/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.notes/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.notes/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.notes/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
```